# Get intermediate nodes using ping

Tags: networking, shell, ping, traceroute, sh

I need to get intermediate nodes when requesting the route through ping.

- I can get the intermediate routes through `traceroute url`, but in the server there's a problem
- I cannot use traceroute. I only need to get the intermediate host ips for my program.

Most of the forums I have read suggested to use `ping -R url`, but that doesn't reflect the intermediate node when I check with ping and traceroute on my local machine.

Is there a way I can get intermediate nodes **only** using ping?
( Without installing any other package like traceroute? )

Comment: Do you have `pathping` available?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do the same kind of tracing by running `ping` several times with increasing time-to-live. The option for specifying a TTL is `-t` on Linux, `-i` on Windows:

```
ping -t 1 $hostname
ping -t 2 $hostname
ping -t 3 $hostname
...and so on.
```

Unlike `ping -R`, this also works with IPv6 (not counting a bug in Windows' ping.exe which makes it show the wrong IP address when in IPv6 mode).

Answer (score 0):

The MTR software, linux command mtr, groups traceroute and ping and get's you a result every second. Available as console and GUI. 
Winmtr is the Windows version of it.

[image: mtr gui output].